# closed property of window?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the use of closed property of window?

By default closed is false.

```
window.closed
false
```

I observed that closed can be set to true, but what is the significance of closed = true?

```
window.closed = true
true
```

After this window remains open.Same behavior with chrome and firefox.

Comment: oh ok , i guess window.closed = true silently failed.

Comment: PS. Your console prints the result of the last evaluated expression, which is `true` in this case. Use `window.closed=1;window.closed`, and the console prints `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`window.closed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.closed) refers to an instance of a window. It's a read-only property, used to determine whether an opened popup/tab/window is still alive or not.

```
var w = window.open();
console.log(w.closed);  // false
w.closed = true;
console.log(w.closed);  // false
w.close();
console.log(w.closed);  // true
```

It's truly read-only:

```
'use strict';
window.closed = false; // TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be useful if you have popups and want to check their existence before modifying properties on them.  MDN has a few good examples
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.closed?action=edit